# Increases in power

Tags: voltage, speed, torque

I have an electric scooter which I would like to boost or mod for more speed.
Currently it runs on a 1600w 48v controller, but what would happen if I changed the controller to a 2000w 48v one, what would be the values increased that I would see?, more torque or more speed.
I understand adding another 12v battery making 60v would be good, but they are heavy batteries and this is not practical.
So, what are my options.

Comment: Adding pedals might work. Maybe another hp for a short time and you'd feel the benefits after a few days.

Answer (score 3):

Just because the controller is rated 1600W doesn't mean that it's delivering 1600W to the motor, and just because you change the controller to a 2000W controller you won't automatically get more power.  The controller may be spec'd conservatively and the batteries and wiring may not be capable of delivering 1600 or 2000 watts.  The motor may not be rated to handle more power either.

The speed is proportional to the effective voltage, so with 48V you may already be getting the maximum top speed you can get assuming the controller is not limiting it in some way.  What you could get with higher power would be faster acceleration (more torque.)

So you would have to check the entire system to see if more power is available, and for more top speed you may have to change the system voltage, the controller, and/or the motor.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was told that increasing voltage from 48 to 60v by adding another 12v battery would marginally increase speed, but this is awkward as you can imagine another 12v SLA block is heavy, I though increasing total wattage would do, maybe not.

Comment: Yes, increasing the voltage would work for a while - if the speed controller could handle it - then the motor will smoke. Probably the controller will smoke first.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a volt meter on the battery to see how low the voltage drops while you are at full speed. It may be that swapping the battery out for a higher capacity 2kW model will yield increased performance in the event the current battery does not have the capacity to maintain the peak voltage under full load.